# How to get coordinates from database and show them on the map fast?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm

I have a database which has lots of car locations(coordinates; lat,lng). I want to get the location of the cars just by giving the coordinates to server and get the locations very fast. The problem is that the number of cars is numerous and if there are millions of records in a table, when requesting with

```
select *
from locations
where (lat >= '$lat-10' and lat <= '$lat+10') and
      (lng >= '$lng-10' and lng <= '$lng+10')
```

it might be normal but it compares millions of coordinates with four conditions and it utilizes resources very much. So is there any algorithm to find the locations very fast? I thought whether it is a good idea to categorize the map of my country with squares and put each section to a separate table in order to find the locations fast. So if a user wants to find the location of a car just by giving her/his current coordinates, SQL will search only in the section(table) that the user currently is. But now the problem is that the number of tables will grow much, maybe 100,000 tables!!

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `car_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `car_code` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lng` tinytext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `locations`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`);
```

or maybe I should use index in SQL? if yes how can I do that? Is this the answer [index](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng)

How can I find the location of cars fast?
Thanks

Comment: Please define 'fast' and 'very fast'. There are literally dozens of ways to do this, both in sql and in application code. Your definition of fast might be very different from my definition. And within the context of an sql answer, we can only guess without seeing your table structure, index definitions, and explain plan.

Comment: update your question and add  your table locations schema

Comment: I mean as fast as possible in order a user not to be waited for more than 3 seconds.

Comment: You need to look into a GIS extension for MySQL if you are concerned about performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you that was the answer I wanted, I've started searching by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you don't need  unuseful conversione between data so use the same data type pr lat and lng in you table schema and query.
(if the lat, lng in db is decimal don't use a string for pass the vars value  .. eventually ise a proper binding )
be sure you have composite index on table locations  on both

select only the column you really need in select and add  these column to your composite index eg:

```
 select col1,col2,col3 
 from locations 
 where (lat >= :lat-10 and lat <= :lat+10) and (lng >= :lng-10 and lng <= :lng+10);

 CREATE INDEX idx_lat_lng ON locations (lat,lng, col1, col2, col3);
```